# To get 401 Unauthorized when I send a Ajax POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, unauthorized

I have been testing very simple Ajax code with post type in Visual Studio 2015~2017,
unfortunately I've always gotton the error message from Browser as like following picture
[image]

Please help me to recognize what's wrong with this issue, thanks

PS:
Client Side

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/Delete",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {    
            alert("=="+ data.d)
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }    
    });
</script>
```

Server Side:

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string Delete()
        {
            return "12334";
        }
    }
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

By the way,I've also found the same problems at Stack Overflow however it isn't work for me too.

AS following pictures are full steps
Step1:
[image]
Step2:
[image]
Step3: to add webform.aspx 
[image]
Step3: to put the code into, I don't know why or what's wrong in fact it is very easy code to use ajax connect to server , please help me thanks a lot

Comment: Try disabling all kinds of authentication. You may look at this answer for a quick (but not recommended) fix. Once we ascertain that authentication is indeed the problem, we can take it from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434215/how-to-disable-forms-authentication

Comment: Hi @RamanpreetSingh thanks very much for your recommend ,but I didn't set anything in my project, so that it shouldn't have happened with Authority statement.

Comment: Hi@RamanpreetSingh , I've put more detail in the content ,hopefully it can let you know about what is going on, thanks

Comment: Could you post your web config file.

Comment: hi @GaganDeep ,I've done ,thanks

Comment: Could you do one thing, wrap this ajax call inside a javascript function. place a <button> on the page and call the javascript function on the button click and see if you still get this error,

Comment: Hi @GaganDeep sorry it isn't worked

Comment: to search server side problems ,it isn't client problem. so that VS could be setup the something in your project

Comment: Hi@a09375447221, Yes I think so,thanks for your clue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it , it will be handle your problem
Step1: to add RouteConfig.cs in your App_Start folder

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

step 2: to add Global.asax.cs

```
Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```